# Is there a way to use PathFinder from GraphAlgoFactory with spring-data

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I took a look at [movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4) and I love it, but I want to use PathFinder from GraphAlgoFactory with spring-data 4.1.1.RELEASE.

I want to create some sort of Roadmap in my db and use the RestController to find a path between two given nodes.
(Basically the second (A*) example from here: [neo4j-docs-graph-algo](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html))

```
PathFinder<WeightedPath> astar = GraphAlgoFactory.aStar(
        PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections(),
        doubleCostEvaluator, estimateEvaluator);
path = astar.findSinglePath(start, end);
```

findSinglePath needs an Object of org.neo4j.graphdb.Node is there a way to get this from a NodeEntity?

The only way I could find is using the EmbeddedDriver and looking up the node myself:

```
EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
Node node = databaseService.findNode(...)
```

Is there an easier way, preferably via HttpDriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP Driver does not provide access to the underlying graph database. You can write a stored procedure and call it via the session/template/repository query methods.

Here are some examples of stored procedures for graph algorithms- https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#graph-algorithms-work-in-progress

Comment: Thank you for your answer. APOC looks very good but I wanted that cost function callback and APOC only works with relationship properties as costfunction.
I guess I could write my own stored procedure as you mentioned, but I don't think I want to do the cost function in cypher, even though it might probably be faster.
I guess I have to find something else. But you helped me a lot.

Comment: If you write a stored procedure, you have access to the underlying Neo4j Java API so even though you'd call it over Cypher, the cost is calculated in the procedure. The source of an example path finding proc is https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/algo/PathFinding.java to give you an idea of what's possible